# Unit tests in Spring MVC Rest - cast issue

Tags: java, unit-testing, spring-mvc, junit, mockito

I am developing simple Rest API app and trying to test it using this tutorial: http://memorynotfound.com/unit-test-spring-mvc-rest-service-junit-mockito/

I have implemented entire `test_get_all_success` unit test using my working Rest API (written in Spring MVC). Unfortunately test cannot run because of following issue.

Here is entire test file:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.when;
import static org.springframework.test.web.client.match.MockRestRequestMatchers.content;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultMatchers.status;

import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.test.context.ContextConfiguration;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner;
import org.springframework.test.context.web.WebAppConfiguration;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc;

import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.*;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.mockito.InjectMocks;
import org.mockito.Mock;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.*;
import org.mockito.MockitoAnnotations;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.request.MockMvcRequestBuilders.*;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultMatchers.*;  
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.setup.MockMvcBuilders;

@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes={MyConfigClass.class})
@WebAppConfiguration
public class ClientTest {  

    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Mock
    private ClientManagerImpl clientManager;

    @InjectMocks
    private ClientController clientController;

    @Before
    public void init(){
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
        mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders
                .standaloneSetup(clientController)
                .build();
    }

    @Test
    public void findAll_ClientsFound_ShouldReturnFoundClients() throws Exception {
        Client a = ...;
        Client b = ...;

        when(clientManager.getClients()).thenReturn(Arrays.asList(a, b));

        mockMvc.perform(get("/clients"))
                .andExpect(status().isOk())             
        .andExpect(content().contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE))
                .andExpect(jsonPath("$", hasSize(2)));

        verify(clientManager, times(1)).getClients();
        verifyNoMoreInteractions(clientManager);
    }

}
```

NetBeans shows error in this line:

```
.andExpect(content().contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE))

incompatible types: RequestMatcher cannot be converted to ResultMatcher
```

Test cannot run because of this error. When I delete this line everything works fine and test is passed.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I don't see anything wrong from what you have posted. Can you post more code from your test method please?

Comment: Thank you for reply, code updated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following static import causes the conflict:

```
import static org.springframework.test.web.client.match.MockRestRequestMatchers.content;
```

[`MockRestRequestMatchers`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/web/client/match/MockRestRequestMatchers.html) class is used for client-side REST testing using [`MockRestServiceServer`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/web/client/MockRestServiceServer.html), but you are testing here MVC application controllers.